# How to identify the Object type?

Tags: delphi, oop, pointers

Lets say I have a Treeview, and it contains items with Object pointers. How can I determine from the selected item what the Object is, so I can access it?

Here is a basic example of some classes and code to give an idea:
Note: TChildObject1 and TChildObject2 inherit from TMyObject.

```
type
  TMyObject = class
  private
    FName: string;
  public
    property Name: string read FName write FName;

    constructor Create(aName: string);
  end;

type
  TChildObject1 = class(TMyObject)
  private
    FSomeString: string;
  public
    property SomeString: string read FSomeString write FSomeString;

    constructor Create(aName: string);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

type
  TChildObject2 = class(TMyObject)
  private
    FSomeInteger: integer;
  public
    property SomeInteger: integer read FSomeInteger write FSomeInteger;

    constructor Create(aName: string);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;
```

Lets say they were created and added to a TTreeview like so:

```
procedure NewChild1(aTreeView: TTreeView; aName: string);
var
  Obj: TChildObject1;
begin
  Obj := TChildObject1.Create(aName);
  try
    aTreeView.Items.AddObject(nil, Obj.Name, Obj);
  finally
    Obj.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure NewChild2(aTreeView: TTreeView; aName: string);
var
  Obj: TChildObject2;
begin
  Obj := TChildObject2.Create(aName);
  try
    aTreeView.Items.AddObject(nil, Obj.Name, Obj);
  finally
    Obj.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // add the items to the tree
  NewChild1(TreeView1, 'Child Object 1');
  NewChild2(TreeView1, 'Child Object 2');
end;
```

Now, when I select a Node in the Treeview, how can I determine which Object class the pointer leads to? I tried this, which is not working:

Note: This does not error, but it does not return the correct value (ie, does not pick up the correct object)

```
procedure TForm1.TreeView1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Obj: TMyObject;
begin
  if TreeView1.Selected <> nil then
  begin
    Obj := TMyObject(TreeView1.Selected.Data);

    if Obj is TChildObject1 then
    begin
      Edit1.Text := 'this node is a child1 object';
    end else
    if Obj is TChildObject2 then
    begin
      Edit1.Text := 'and this node is child 2 object';
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I could do it something like below, but I don't think is the right way, it means a lot of checking, declaring, assigning etc.

```
procedure TForm1.TreeView1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ChildObj1: TChildObject1;
  ChildObj2: TChildObject2;
begin
  if TreeView1.Selected <> nil then
  begin
    if TreeView1.Selected.Text = 'Child Object 1' then
    begin
      ChildObj1 := TreeView1.Selected.Data;    
      Edit1.Text := ChildObj1.SomeString;
    end else
    if TreeView1.Selected.Text = 'Child Object 2' then
    begin
      ChildObj2 := TreeView1.Selected.Data;  
      Edit1.Text := IntToStr(ChildObj2.SomeInteger);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Tips and advice appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem is which you are freeing the memory of the object that you are adding to the treeview. So  the data  of the nodes points to a invalid location.

To assign the objects to a node use a code like this

```
  Obj := TChildObject1.Create(aName);
  aTreeView.Items.AddObject(nil, Obj.Name, Obj);
```

and when you need dispose the data you can call the `Free` method for each node.

```
 for i:= 0 to TreeView1.Items.Count - 1 do
 begin
  Obj:= TMyObject(TreeView1.Items.Item[i].Data);
  if Assigned(Obj) then
   Obj.Free;
 end;
```

Comment: +1 Im very much learning OOP, for some reason I thought I could assign Obj to the selected node data but I guess not, I am freeing it too early. Just edited my code, it now identifies the correct object :)

Comment: @RRUZ: I would use the `TTreeView.OnDeletion` event to free the objects instead of using a loop, eg: `procedure TForm1.TreeView1Deletion(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode); begin TObject(Node.Data).Free; end;`